# How do compilers handle records and unions?

Tags: data-structures, struct, compiler-construction, union, theory

My class was assigned a project to create a simple compiler that does basic operations over integers, I, however, have already figured a way of implementing pointers and would like to implement records and unions as well in order to increase the range of functionalities.
How does the compiler interpret this C code for example:
`struct name {int x; char x;};`

Note I am not expecting a very practical answer as i do intend on thinking on the matter but would like some theory behind this matter if it's possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a compiled definition of struct look like in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211852/how-does-a-compiled-definition-of-struct-look-like-in-c), with the comment [structs are not compiled, they are declared. Functions get compiled though.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211882/724039)

Comment: Aggregate types are generally first class in a typical mid-level compiler IR. Without optimisation, they compile down to code that creates allocations (large enough to store the heterogeneous components - often with padding for alignment purposes) and each member access is mapped to an offset in the structure/record.

Unions are typically not first class features, you implement them by aliasing an area of memory (large enough to store the largest type in the union). Rust does this, for example: it aliases (via bitcast) an array, following the tag field, of each variant.