# How to create "objects" of struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm writing a ring buffer library in C and I'm trying to make it possible to have several ring buffers by making "objects" of a typedef struct. This is the struct in my .h library:

```
//ringbuffer.h

// declare variables in struct
typedef struct Ringbuffer
{
    int* buff;           // ring buffer
    int  buffSize;       // ring buffer size
    // more vars here
}ringbuffer;
```

This is how I initialize the buffer and it's size and also free the memory.

```
//ringbuffer.c

//initialize buffer
void ringbuffer_init(int buff_size, ringbuffer *a)                              
{
// allocate memory to buffer
    a->buff = malloc(buff_size * sizeof(int));  
}

// empty the buffer
void ringbuffer_empty(ringbuffer *a)
{
    free(a->buff);
}
```

To make a parallell to C++, I would like to initialize it so that I could be writing something equal to `Ringbuffer buffer1;` and `Ringbuffer buffer2` in C. Right now I solve this problem like this:

```
// example.c

#include "ringbuffer.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    // create two ringbuffer instances by allocating memory
    ringbuffer* buff1 = malloc(sizeof(ringbuffer));
    ringbuffer* buff2 = malloc(sizeof(ringbuffer));

    // initialize the two buffers
    ringbuffer_init(BUFFER_SIZE, buff1);
    ringbuffer_init(BUFFER_SIZE, buff2);

    // use the buffers in some way here   

    free(buff1);
    free(buff2);
}
```

This means that the user of my library would have to allocate memory and also free it. This doesn't seem like a good implementation. How can I do this in a more delicate way?

The complete .h, .c and example.c files can be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/mariugul/Ring-buffer-C).

Comment: The code needs to do something when it wants a ring buffer, right? And when the code is no longer going to need a ring buffer, it also has to do something, right?

Comment: Why can't they do `ringbuffer buff1; ringbuffer buff2;`?

Comment: I edited the question to include the functions for initialize and empty in the .c file for more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can take an object-oriented approach and create a constructor that initializes the struct and returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory.

Example:

```
struct Ringbuffer *Ringbuffer_create()
{
    struct Ringbuffer *self = malloc(sizeof(struct Ringbuffer))
    /* Initiate the other struct members here too */
    ...
    return self;
}
```

In the main file you can write the following:

```
struct ringbuffer *buff1 = Ringbuffer_create();
```

I also recommend to create a destructor function so that you can easily destroy the "object".

```
void Ringbuffer_destroy(struct Ringbuffer **self)
{
    /* Free the allocated memory here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the straightforward way that you mentioned already:

```
#include "ringbuffer.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    // create two ringbuffer instances by defining variables
    ringbuffer buff1;
    ringbuffer buff2;

    // initialize the two buffers
    ringbuffer_init(BUFFER_SIZE, &buff1);
    ringbuffer_init(BUFFER_SIZE, &buff2);

    // use the buffers in some way here   
}
```

Comment: This works! I guess what confused me when I tried this was I didn't use the &buff1 and therefore it didn't work. How does this method differ from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472132/11042379)?

Comment: This other answer "just" moves `malloc()` and `free` into functions of the library. The user still has to remember to call `Ringbuffer_destroy()` to avoid memory leaks. The defined variables of my proposal are deallocated at the end of the block they live in. Not discussed here at all: `static` variables, and freeing the memory used for the buffered values by `ringbuffer_init()`. If you do this in `Ringbuffer_destroy()` you'll gain a bit of convenience, so [@ZeppRock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472132/11042379) might be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

You can have constructor inside struct , see the following

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                               
#include<stdlib.h>                                                              

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10                                                          

typedef struct Ringbuffer                                                       
{                                                                               
    int* buff;           // ring buffer                                         
    int  buffSize;       // ring buffer size                                    
    Ringbuffer(int buffer_size) {                                               
        buff = (int *)malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(int));                        
    };                                                                          
    ~Ringbuffer() {                                                             
        if (buff)                                                               
            free(buff);                                                         
    };                                                                          
}ringbuffer;                                                                    

int main () {                                                                   


    ringbuffer buff1(BUFFER_SIZE);                                              
    ringbuffer buff2(BUFFER_SIZE);                                              

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but it does not compile for me!

Comment: did you compile using gcc or g++? you need to compile using g++

Comment: I am using visual studio with a C++ template to compile my .c files, so I'm not sure which compiler is used. Why would I need to compile with a g++ compiler for it to work if I'm writing everything in C?

Comment: @ChauhanTs No, you can't.

Comment: @MariusGulbrandsen because ChauhanTs has written C++ code instead of C.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4

Also relevant: [What does a compiled C++ class look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211262/what-does-a-compiled-c-class-look-like/3211404#3211404)

Comment: Answers here should be mostly self-contained. If those links break, this answer becomes worthless.